# What happens if you erase a married Mii in Tomodachi Life?

Tags: tomodachi-life

What happens if you erase a married Mii in Tomodachi Life?
I want to delete one of my married because he and his wife had a huge fight and they said "Things aren't going so well" but I picked "work it out" and they worked it out and now I really want to delete one of them.

Comment: By 'erase', did you mean delete from the Mii channel or remove from the game?

Comment: Removing a Mii in Tomodachi Life.

Answer (score 1):

Removing a married Mii will result in the relationship broken up (as if the removed islander never existed).  The house will disappear and the spouse will look for a "new" spouse.  If they have a child that is grown up, the child will still remain, but not if it isn't.